# Как сгенерировать и запостить картинку в инстаграм с сайта на vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, instagram-api

У меня есть сайт на vue, и есть страница с рандомными предсказаниями. Можно ли как-то сгенерировать картинку с этим предсказанием или что-то типа того и чтобы можно было поделиться ею в инсте по кнопке на сайте?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Можно всё, если очень захотеть))